# Div tags with float left not printing properly

Tags: css, css-float

I have a layout that has a container div tag and some nested floating div tags. I'm using them in this manner to have two column effect (rather than do table cells). On the web page, everything renders fine. But when I print, the floating ones aren't showing up correctly. It's a sequence of 2 sets of container div/floating divs and then a full width div tag (no floating). Here's the code:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px; border-top: 1px solid #000000; padding: 5px; font-size: 0;">
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; vertical-align: top; font-size: 11px;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Provider: </span>
    Name here
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; vertical-align: top; font-size: 11px;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Location: </span>
    Name<br/>
    Street Address<br/>
    City, State Zip<br/>
    Phone
  </div>
</div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 5px; border-top: 1px solid #000000; padding: 5px; font-size: 0;">
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; vertical-align: top; font-size: 11px;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Appointments:</span>
    <br />
    No appointments scheduled
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; vertical-align: top; font-size: 11px;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Care Team:</span>
    <br />
    Name Here
  </div>
</div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; border-top: 1px solid #000000;">
  <span style="font-weight: bold;">Referrals:</span>
  <br />
  No referrals available
</div>
```

As stated, everything renders correctly on the web page. Thanks to @avrahamcool I have it fixed so that the top border lines are showing up correctly. However, when I use IE9, I am getting what looks like the following:

---

**Provider:**  Name here
**Location:** Name
Street Address
City, State Zip
Phone

---

**Appointments:**
No appointments scheduled
**Care Team:**
Name Here

---

**Referrals:**
No referrals available

It's working fine in Chrome. The provider/location and appointments/care team are split into two columns between the border lines when it's printed (and shows up fine on the screen)

Comment: Print rendering varies widely across browsers. You may want to look at providing a server-side PDF engine instead.

Comment: not an answer to your question, but as best practice you should not involve your markup and styling together. use an external CSS file.

Comment: @avrahamcool typically that's what I do. In this particular case, I have no choice but to use in-line styles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've completely recreated your markup, so I can work with it.

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/htWWw/) is the result. (notice how beautiful this is?)

I've tested it in IE10, IE9, IE8, FF, Chrome.
also, printed from each one, and it works like a charm.

If you have to write your HTML & CSS combined (I don't see a reason for that.. but who am I to judge) I will try to help you apply my solution to your HTML.

So, the main Idea is to lose the `float` thing altogether, and use `inline-block` instead.

but, `inline-block` adds extra-spacing to the elements (caused by new-lines in the markup), causing 50% to be a little more than that, therefor making the columns not to fit in one row.
I've used one of many tricks to resolved that issue. by applying `font-size:0;` on the container, and reapplying font size on his children.
also, I had to `verticaly-align:top;` the columns.

so, to summarize, this is the end result.

**New HTML markup**

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Column">
        <span class="Header">Provider:</span>
        <span>Name here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Column">
        <span class="Header">Location:</span>
        <span>Name</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Street Address</span>
        <br/>
        <span>City, State Zip</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Phone</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Column">
        <span class="Header">Appointments:</span>
        <br/>
        <span>No appointments scheduled</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Column">
        <span class="Header">Care Team:</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Name Here</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Container">
    <span class="Header">Referrals:</span>
    <br/>
    <span>No referrals available</span>
</div>
```

**New CSS**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.Container
{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    font-size: 0;
}
    .Container *
    {
        font-size: medium;
    }
.Container .Column
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
    .Container .Header
    {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

**Edit:**
for some reason, I've dropped your padding. so [here](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/htWWw/1/) is a fiddle with padding in the container (all the rest is the same as before)

**Edit 2 inline-style**

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 5px;border-top: 1px solid #000000;font-size: 0;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;vertical-align: top;font-size: medium;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Provider:</span>
        <span>Name here</span>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;vertical-align: top;font-size: medium;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Location:</span>
        <span>Name</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Street Address</span>
        <br/>
        <span>City, State Zip</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Phone</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 5px;border-top: 1px solid #000000;font-size: 0;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;vertical-align: top;font-size: medium;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Appointments:</span>
        <br/>
        <span>No appointments scheduled</span>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;vertical-align: top;font-size: medium;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Care Team:</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Name Here</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 5px;border-top: 1px solid #000000;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Referrals:</span>
    <br/>
    <span>No referrals available</span>
</div>
```

**Inline-Style V2**

so, its probably the font fix that doesn't work for you. It's hard for me to debug, because it's working fine for me. so lets try another approach.
this time, we will eliminate the spacing between columns by deleting the new line from the markup. try this new markup.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 5px;border-top: 1px solid #000000;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;vertical-align: top;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Provider:</span>
        <span>Name here</span>
    </div><div style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;vertical-align: top;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Location:</span>
        <span>Name</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Street Address</span>
        <br/>
        <span>City, State Zip</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Phone</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 5px;border-top: 1px solid #000000;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;vertical-align: top;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Appointments:</span>
        <br/>
        <span>No appointments scheduled</span>
    </div><div style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;vertical-align: top;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Care Team:</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Name Here</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 5px;border-top: 1px solid #000000;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Referrals:</span>
    <br/>
    <span>No referrals available</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to have the in-line styles. This is part of a .xslt file that reads in xml and affects the layout for on screen display. Additionally, the xml file can be downloaded and we want to send the xslt along with it. I know I can't use an external .css file but it MIGHT be possible to have the styles defined at the top of the .xslt (don't quote me on that). However, to be safe, in-line styles are what I'm using. I will try to implement this and see if it works

Comment: If you need further help on porting the solution to inline-style, let me know.

Comment: I'm pulling the style attributes out of the css that you've got here and putting them inline in the appropriate places. I think i put everything in correctly, but now when I print, the right hand columns end up underneath the left hand columns

Comment: i've got the font-size: 0; in the container style yes. I put the font-size medium in the container/column style. How should I apply it to make it work in-line? Everythign else is working (the top border lines are all in the right places and spacing is good with the padding now)

Comment: check-out the updated solution. works on all the browsers I mentioned earlier + print. if you need IE7 support, we need to apply a little fix.

Comment: looks like it's working in Chrome, but having that same problem in IE9. I can dig around for a fix for IE9 probably. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: its weird. I'm testing it on IE9 (IE10 on IE9 mode), and its printing fine.. can you describe the result so I try to find what the difference is? (an img will be ideal)

Comment: edited the question with the new example of what's happening in IE9. thanks for the help

Comment: It's hard for me to debug, because it's working fine for me. but try the new solution I've Just updated.

Comment: I hope its working, because I really can't see were the problem is.

Comment: still not working. I'll do some more digging and try to debug. I really appreciate the help. It's better than it was for sure

Comment: as last resort.. instead of 50% give it something like 48% just to be sure. if its still splits to two rows, that means your printer don't recognize inline-block.

Comment: BTW do you have IE9? or using IE9 mode in IE10? (if you're using the emulator, check that the document mode is also IE9, and not IE5)

Comment: I'm using IE9, not IE9 mode in IE10. And the printer seems to be fine with inline-block because it printed fine from Chrome. I will try the 48% and see if that works. I also tried taking out the width from the second column and it was still not working correctly, but I'll put both to 48% and see if that works. Thanks

Comment: Never could get it to work. the right column div still wants to show up under the left column div

Comment: in extreme cases like this, I think its ok to use tables for layout.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that but that's the route I went with. I have other places where tables make sense because it's tabular data but I don't like to use tables for layout if I can avoid it. Thanks for the help though. I really appreciate it. I tried everything in my arsenal

Answer (score 0):

media="print" like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Doing this should make it look the same as web page

and yes depeding on the browser like isherwood said if that is what you are pointing at.

Comment: I've got to do this with in-line styles unfortunately. If I switch to table layouts for the float left pieces, then it works, but I want to avoid table layouts if I can. I also can't set a height on the div tags (the containers or the floats) because it can vary.